# display the number of items in the cart on virtuemart joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I'm using the code below to display a number based on the number of items in the cart. If there's 1 item, then the number 1 is generated, 2 items and 2 is displayed etc etc.

the problem is that it displays the quantity for the product with an id of [1]. how can change this to make it work for all product ids?

```
<?php $array = unserialize($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']); 
$amount = $array->products[1]->amount;
if ($amount != 0){ echo $amount; } else { echo 0; } ?>
```

the [1] is the product id. how do i change it to accept all product ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting to loop through all products? Something like ...

```
<?php 
    $array = unserialize($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']); 
    foreach($array->products as $product){
        $amount = $product->amount;
        if ($amount != 0){ echo $amount; } else { echo 0; } 
    }
?>
```

Adding all products ...

```
<?php 
    $array = unserialize($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']); 
    $total = 0;
    foreach($array->products as $product){
        $total += $product->amount;
    }
    echo "Total Products: " . $total;
?>
```

Comment: I want to include all products

Comment: @aqibjr1 - The `foreach` loop will display the amount for all products in the products array ... is this not what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the code but the problem is it is displaying 11111 when i have 5 products in the cart. is there any way i can add the integers to produce the number 5 instead of 11111

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing, I can only guess ... Hopefully the examples will get you headed in the right direction ...