# How to display just the number of products in cart Virtuemart

Tags: virtuemart

I am running Virtuemart 2.0.18 and Joomla 1.5. What I need to accomplish is to just display the total number of products in the cart with a number like "10". I have a cart image and want to place that next to the image.

I have found similar questions-but, the answers did not apply-nor work for my situation.

I did find this thread on stackoverflow: [display the number of items in the cart on virtuemart joomla 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006030/display-the-number-of-items-in-the-cart-on-virtuemart-joomal-2-5)

That did not solve my problem:

```
<?php 
    $array = unserialize($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']); 
    $total = 0;
    foreach($array->products as $product){
        $total += $product->amount;
    }
    echo "Total Products: " . $total;
?>
```

This only works if I go to my cart (as the cart is ran by cookies). The php isn't working also if I add a few products the number count is off. Basically the whole code does not function at all.

Is there a JavaScript that will work to access the cookies and retrieve the amount of products in the cart, or is there a similar way to do this with PHP?

Thank you in advance for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people at Virtuemart forums I decided to duplicate a joomla module. I duplicated the Virtuemart cart module, then I removed some code and CSS classes, and now I have a module that will just display the total number of products in the cart!

Here is a link to that package-use it as you would like:
http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=114256.0